# Implementing a Managed JAVABean throws an Error: "Can't instantiate class"

Tags: jsf, javabeans, xpages

I have tried to implement a JavaBean in my Application. I'm new on this topic and as it didn't work I got two steps back and tried the same with a HelloWorld example which I had done my self some month ago. This time it didn't work, too.
I use the 8.5.3 Designer Client and we have a 8.5.2 Development Server.
I set in the Application property the flag for compatibility 8.5.2.

**The JAVABean Code looks like this:**

```
package net.ta.java.Backend;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyHalloWelt implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String HalloWelt;

    public String getHalloWelt() {
        return HalloWelt;
    }

    public void setHalloWelt(String halloWelt) {
        HalloWelt = halloWelt;
    }

    public MyHalloWelt() {
        HalloWelt = "Hallo neue Welt!";
    }
}
```

**The faces-config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>Test</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
  <!--AUTOGEN-START-BUILDER: Automatically generated by IBM Lotus Domino Designer. Do not modify.-->
  <!--AUTOGEN-END-BUILDER: End of automatically generated section-->
</faces-config>
```

**The XPage function-call:**

```
 <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{Test.HalloWelt}"></xp:text>
```

**The Exception:**

> Exception javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: Can't instantiate class: 'net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt'..
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt
>   javax.faces.FacesException: Can't instantiate class:
>   'net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt'.. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt Can't instantiate class:
>   'net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt'.. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt class
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt

I followed a hint in this forum which says that it could be an bug with the JAVA Class Design Element new in 8.5.3. Like they said in the post I tried to put my class manually in the src\ path but it didn't work - same error.
I thought it is a compatibility issue with our 8.5.2 Server but locally the same error.

I hope someone could help me. I am at a loss with this... Thanks!

Michael

EDIT:
Thank you very much to all of the people helped me with this issue so far.
Now it works if I opend the XPage with my Notes CLient. It doesen't matter if the database is on the server or local. It doesen't work if I open it with a Browser. If I do so the error is still there.

Comment: Is your */src* folder added to your build path?

Comment: OK finaly I have managed to make it work propably on a lokal Replika on my client. So I guess it has something to do with my Domino Server. 
Does anyone knows if I can use ManagedBeans under 8.5.2? - I didn't find anything against it...

Comment: @SvenHasselbach I have made so many changes that I couldn't really tell. Maybe it wasn't. - The question is why it works probably under my 8.5.3 Client and NOT on my 8.5.2 Server. Are there any limitations?

Comment: Yes, you can use managed beans with 8.5.2. The limitation of 8.5.2 is that there is no "Java" element/Folder. If you are running your code on a 8 5.2 server you have to configure the build path manually.

Comment: What should be in the buildpath? - As far as I see the configuration is correct. :/

Comment: Please post our build path settings

Comment: OK Great I have it... Thanks a lot for your help. It's a great community and I hope I could give something back in near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem consists of more then one part:
1. I had a typo in the spelling of my Bean-Attribute "HalloWelt" => "halloWelt"
2. My Server don't have the German Language-pack installed, which caused the misleading Errormessages concerning the resources files.
 
3. The main Problem finally is the Domino Server 8.5.2 didn't recognize the "Class/JAVA" Folder new in Notes/Domino 8.5.3! If I move my JAVABean to a new created "src" folder the JAVABean get recognized and everything works fine. - A little confusing is the XPage works fine in Notes Client before moving the java file. Only browsers produce the error...

Thanks to all of You provided me with the needed hints. I have learned a lot more about JAVA Development as I had expected. :)

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I come across this issue I choose in DDE Project - Clean... and clean the whole project. This recompiles all your Code, Xpages etc...

Besides that, I always assign an ID to my managed-bean like:

```
<managed-bean id="Test">
<managed-bean-name>Test</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

I am not really sure if that is required or not. As far as I can see, the bean tries to load your class so I assume, it is not.

Hope that helps-
Michael

Comment: The DDE Project Clean was a very good hint. I found one other Problem with my DB and could fix it... BUT my current problem is still not solved - thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I assume you implemented the Fix Sven suggested? => value="#{Test.halloWelt}"
Afer all your changes: What is the error message you get in the error log (error-log-0.xml)?

Comment: One more thing: In DDE in the Application Properties on the XPages tab: enable "Display XPage Runtime Error page" for easier debugging... (if not done already)

Comment: The fix I got from Sven is implemented. "Display XPage Runtime Error page" is enabled - otherwise I wouldn't see this error. - But a silly question: Where do I find the "error-log-0.xml"? :/

Comment: The error log can be found on your server in <dominodata>\domino\workspace\logs. BTW: I copied your code and built a project which works on my server (with Svens fox for the computed field value)... My experience is that you are better off cleaning the project than choosing build or build automatically

Comment: ok thanks - very interesting. What Systemconfiguration are you using?
Server?
Client?

Comment: DDE: 853 EN, Server: 9 EN (Win) and 853 EN (LIN) (no languagepacks..), Browser: Firefox 17 DE

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in Java perspective/Package explorer view your classes are under "Code/Java" category. In Java perspective again, right click on project, Build Path/Configure Build Path... Make sure in first "Source" tab your source folder is listed.

Comment: Thanks - the error Message changes... ;)
My Source was not in the Code/JAVA category. After moving the code right there and recompileing of my Project - the following message apears:
Exception
javax.faces.FacesException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle javax.faces.Messages, key de
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle javax.faces.Messages, key de
Can't find resource for bundle javax.faces.Messages, key de

Comment: @Michael: 1. Your server does not have the german language files installed correctly. 2. Please change your EL in your XPage to *value="#{Test.halloWelt}"*.

Comment: @SvenHasselbach Ah Ok - didn't see that with the lowercase letter. - But sadly it doesn't help. What about the German Language Files? - How can I Fix this?

Comment: @Michael: Install the german language pack. To see the error message of your managed bean you have to change your browser to a language installed on the server. Then you should get the error message.

Comment: @SvenHasselbach OK - Now i have changed my Client Setings to english and this error disapears... BUT now i have again the follwoing message:
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: Can't instantiate class: 'net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt'.. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt
javax.faces.FacesException: Can't instantiate class: 'net.ta.java.Backend.MyHalloWelt'.. etc.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of declaring global variables don't initialize them and initialization has to be done  with in the constructor,in the exception page root cause will be displayed including Code line no.